# Visual Studio 2012 missing frameworks

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 today, and i was excited, because i wanted to experiment with the latest framework version (.net 4.5). But it seems like Visual Studio 2012 doesnt show .net 4.0 and 4.5 in the New Projects dialog. I have had a simlar problem with Visual Studio 2010, but the lower framework versions (3.0, 2.0) didnt show up there. Does anyone know how to get them to show up? Thanks :)

Comment: What kind of project were you trying to create? Could you show us a screenshot?

Comment: I'm trying to make a console app, also a screenshot http://prntscr.com/ea3ky

Comment: Doesn't that <More Frameworks> link send you do the download site?

Comment: Which version and edition of Visual Studio 2012 did you install?  I just checked a copy of Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 RC and it shows both 4.0 and 4.5 in addition to the three versions shown in your screenshot.

Comment: I think, once you install .net framework version 4.0 & 4.5 those should show up in the New Project dialog

Answer (score 5):

You probably do not have the Windows 8.1 SDK installed. Visual Studio 2012, nor its updates, link the .NET Framwork 4.5 libraries for development.

- [Windows 8.1 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/br229516)

You don't have to install the full SDK if you are just looking for the option to build web apps, just the .NET Framework 4.5.1 option in the installer. The full install is about 1.1GB, but just the .NET installer is only 72MB.

For those reading this that have not updated their copy of Visual Studio 2012, make sure you also have these installed:

- [Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.visualstudio.com/news/2013-nov-13-vs)
- [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Installing tools from SDK helped me to see target framework 4.5.1 - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely the case that your VS 2012 install is corrupted. Uninstalling and reinstalling it should fix this issue.

Others have documented this issue (with both VS 2012 RP and RTM):

[VS2012 RTM missing .net 4.5 and mvc project templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720659/vs2012-rtm-missing-net-4-5-and-mvc-project-templates)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/17ff0bb3-e37e-4978-a5a1-c30a8cef1dfe

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with VS2012 and fixed it by using a working install on another PC.

Copy the **C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework** 
folder from the good install into the folder on the failed install.

Target frameworks showed back up when I started VS2012, haven't run into any issues since.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual studio 2012 ultimate WIN 7 32 bit. I didn't need to uninstall VS. I have just repaired it and now it's working for me.. 
After repaired it I got this error msg.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mandi/archive/2013/08/21/visual-studio-2012-quot-the-event-log-file-is-full-quot-error-message.aspx

I simply ignore it and using it..

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem.Tried these,  but none of them worked:
- repair VisualStudio 2012
- uninstall and  reinstall VisualStudio 2012
- install VisualStudio 2013

This worked for me:
- add or remove programs-> Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack
right click ->Repair