# VS2012 RTM missing .net 4.5 and mvc project templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-4.5

On Windows 8 RTM and just installed Vs2012 Ultimate RTM, I'm unable to create a .net 4.5 project nor a .net 4 or 4.5 ASP.NET MVC project.  I've done a repair of VS2012, which did not fix it.  Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

[image: Missing .NET 4.5]

[image: Missing ASP.NET MVC 3 and 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your install is probably corrupted. VS 2012 needs .net 4.5 to run, so something has gone wrong if it's not available.

I would try uninstalling and reinstalling. It's brute force but it generally works.

Comment: Yep... I guess a repair doesn't really repair anything.  Uninstall/Reinstall fixed it.

Comment: The other answer below does not require a full uninstall + install and worked for me! (Windows 7 64-bit pro + VS2012 ultimate)

Answer (score 10):

I also had the same problem.. 
Doing the following procedure solved it.

Copy the folder `\packages\WPT` from the visual studio 2012 installer CD to your desktop.

Uninstall the following in this order..

1. aspnetmvc4vs11tools.msi
2. aspnetmvc4.msi
3. aspnetmvc3vs11tools.msi
4. aspnetmvc3.msi

Then install these in this order.

1. aspnetmvc3.msi
2. aspnetmvc3vs11tools.msi
3. aspnetmvc4.msi
4. aspnetmvc4vs11tools.msi

Trying to repair didn't fix the problem. You have to remove and install these..

Hope this will help...

Comment: @Sen Jacob not able to uninstall `aspnetmvcvs11tools`.  i got a warning saying `A later version of Microsoft Asp.net MVC4- visual Studio 2012 Tools is already installed.` . how can i fix this . mvc4 is the latest version i have , i don't know which one is more higher than this

Comment: @joshua Are you using MVC4 for VS 2010? If yes, remove it and try again.

Comment: @joshua - did that remedy it? I'm in the same state.

Comment: @SenJacob , no pal i don't have VS2010 installed nor related tool.

Comment: @JakeHackl i did the brute force, formatted the whole goddam machine. but i wont suggest you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have the Windows 8.1 SDK installed. Visual Studio 2012, nor its updates, link the .NET Framwork 4.5 libraries for development.

- [Windows 8.1 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/br229516)

You don't have to install the full SDK if you are just looking for the option to build web apps, just the .NET Framework 4.5.1 option in the installer. The full install is about 1.1GB, but just the .NET installer is only 72MB.

For those reading this that have not updated their copy of Visual Studio 2012, make sure you also have these installed:

- [Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.visualstudio.com/news/2013-nov-13-vs)
- [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change .net framework version to 4.5